# Make ping show hostnames instead of IPv6 addresses

Tags: ipv6, ping, hosts

When I use the command `ping ff02::1%eth0` to get a response from all IPv6 hosts in the network segment, I get responses from a bunch of link-local (`fe80::`) addresses (LLIPs).

In order to figure out which hosts are (or are not) responding, I then have to use `arp` to see the MAC address associated with the IPv4 address, and then try to match them up with the IPv6 address to figure out which host is which.

Although I am starting to remember which MAC address belongs to which host, I'd much rather have the system automatically map the LLIPs back to hostnames.

Is there any mechanism to do this?

I have tried putting the LLIP in `/etc/hosts`, with and without the zone (`%interface` suffix), and this allows me to ping a single host by name, but it is not used by `ping` to convert IP responses back to hostnames.

`ping` has the `-n` option to avoid name resolution which hints to me that what I am trying to achieve is possible, I'm just not quite sure how to do it!

Comment: I just examined `ping`'s behavior using `strace` (on Kali Linux): `ping` does not look up `/etc/hosts`. My suspicion is that you have to script just what you did manually. ~ Using IPv6 multicast to find out what hosts are on the LAN sounds a bit odd for several reasons, moreover, some nodes might choose to not answer - a more aggressive approach is to use a tool like `alive6` from the THC-IPv6 suite. Looks slightly like an XY problem - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: `strace` tells me `ping` does read `/etc/hosts` if I supply a hostname on the command line, so not sure exactly what governs those lookups.  I am setting up some headless Raspberry Pi systems with IPv6 and sometimes due to typos they will lose their IPv4 and/or IPv6 addresses, so I am using this to figure out whether they are actually up and I can connect to them to fix the problem, without going to the physical box to do so.